# The problem with adding a custom domain in postman

Tags: postman, cloudflare

I want to make a custom domain for project documentation in postman. I added a TXT record and CNAME in the DNS section of Cloudflare. But when I click on the `Verify Domain` button, an error appears: `Something went wrong No CNAME record found for this domain`.

Comment: I am also facing the exact same issue and have raise it to the postman community

https://community.postman.com/t/unable-to-verify-custom-domain-no-cname-record-found-for-this-domain/12552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from cloudflare side:

When a CNAME record is orange clouded we basically treat it like an A record AND cloudflare obfuscate the origin and just return the IP address. As a result if you do a DNS query for CNAME with an orange clouded record you won’t see it (but an A record query will return the destination IP).

For services which are looking to validate with a specific value obfuscation = bad. So to prevent this you’ll want to make sure the record is :grey: not :orange:.